# Found two representations of same collection in Grails

Tags: grails

when I use the bellow code see the exception Found two representations of same collection.
how can fix this problem?

```
class ProductModel implements Serializable{
static auditable = true
String name
Product product
Guarantee guarantee
String status
Integer width
Integer height
Integer weight



static hasMany = [variationValues: VariationValue, prices: Price]

static composites = ["prices"]

static mapping = {
    sort 'id'
    prices cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    searchKeys type: 'text'
}
```

in ProductModelController I have this code for delete()

```
def delete() {
def pricemodel = Price.findAllByProductModel(productModelInstance).findAll()
pricemodel.each { price ->
    productModelInstance.removeFromPrices(price)
}
productModelInstance.save()
pricemodel.each {
    it.delete()
}

    productModelInstance.delete(flush: true)
```

Comment: Could you post the `Price` domain class?  I also tried to edit your post to clean it up some but there isn't enough non-code to satisfy  the requirements for editing.

Comment: `Price implements Serializable{
    static auditable = true
    Double price
    Double rialPrice = 0D
    Currency currency
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    ProductModel productModel

    static mapping = {
        sort 'startDate'
    }

    static constraints = {
        price(min: 0D)
        rialPrice()
        currency(nullable: true)
        startDate(nullable: false)
        endDate(nullable: true)
        productModel(nullable:true)
    }
}`-[tag:tylerwal]